# confusion because i can't figure out what is changing the attribute of the object of a class in python

Tags: python, class, object, instance, instance-variables

**Here is my code**
`

```
class Cats:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
        #print(self.name,name,"hello")
    def change_name(self,new_name):
        self.name=new_name
        return 0
        #print(new_name)

cat1=Cats("lion")
print(cat1)
print(cat1.name)


cat2=cat1.change_name("tiger")
print(cat1.name)
print(cat1)
print(cat2)
```

** **Here is the output** with my comments/opinion on the side (pls correct me if i am wrong):
**
`<__main__.Cats object at 0x7f84272d7640>`   error because I tried to print the object cat1

`lion` seems fine coz i printed the attribute of the object and since the name given while initialising was lion, it printed lion

`tiger` THIS IS WHAT I DON'T UNDERSTAND. why is this output tiger and not lion. what exactly caused this change? Bcoz when I do <<cat2=cat1.change_name("tiger") , it should just assign the value 0 to cat2 but why did it change the value in cat1 ?

`<__main__.Cats object at 0x7f84272d7640>` error bcoz i tried to print a class

`0` seems fine coz chane_name function returns 0 which is assigned to cat2

I was expecting the value of cat1.name to remain the same (it should have remained lion and not changed to tiger)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `cat1.change_name("tiger")`, a few things happen:

1. The name `self` is bound to the same object as `cat1`.
2. As a result, `cat1.name` is changed from `"lion"` to `"tiger"`
3. `change_name` returns `0`, not a new instance of `Cats`.

After this call, `cat1.name` evaluates to `"tiger"`, not `"lion"`, because the value has changed.

`print(cat1)` outputs your "error message" because `print` implicitly calls `str` on its argument, and since `Cats` does not define `__str__`, `object.__str__` is used instead, and that produces the string you see.

`print(cat2)` output `0` because that's the value that was assigned to `cat2` as the return value of `cat1.change_name("tiger")`.